# Receber entrada de dados como valor literal Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, criptografia, aes

Desenvolvendo um algoritmo de criptografia, em certo momento o usuário irá inserir a mensagem a ser descriptografada. A mensagem será inserida em bytes, no formato `b'\xf4\x88A\x0f1\xab\x91\x93\xa7-\xc9\xe7\x99:\x0c\xa3'`.

O problema é que ao inserir este valor no `input`, ele é recebido na variável como se fosse uma string, o que gera erro. Da mesma forma, se fizer uma nova conversão para bytes, do valor recebido como string, também irá gerar erro, pois estará convertendo uma mensagem "já convertida".

Existe uma maneira de fazer com que o dado seja recebido como bytes, de forma que eu possa simplesmente enviar para a função e fazer a descriptografia?

P.S.1 Quando tento através do `msg = bytes(input("Mensagem a ser decifrada:  "))` retorna o erro `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`

P.S.2 Quando passo a mensagem em bytes direto como argumento a função funciona sem problemas: `ofb(chave, b'q\xbb3\xd8\xab\x1a2AM\xb0?\x8a\n\xc6\xd1\xce', op)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se bem entendi, você quer que o usuário digite \xbb3 e o Python entenda isso como um caractere especial, correto? Na verdade esta é apenas uma forma de fazer, você poderia adotar qualquer outra convenção, como #(bb3) e decodificar a string você mesmo.

Para usar o formato Python com o mínimo de trabalho extra, você poderia tentar usar eval(string_do_usuario), mas é extremamente inseguro porque a string pode conter código.

```
>>> x = eval("'bla\x88ible'")
>>> x
'bla\x88ible'
```

Exemplo de como um conteúdo malicioso pode "vazar" do eval():

```
>>> x = eval("print('raqueado')")
raqueado
>>> x
```